# Проблемы с пиксельным представлением относительных размеров

Tags: css, css3

При задании относительных величин - позиций и размеров при помощи `rem` и `em` браузер расчитывает абсолютные единицы (пиксели) по своим алгоритмам, каждый бреузер по-своему. При размере в `51.5333px` два одинаковых блока (`:before` и `:after` слева и справа от элемента) отображаются по-разному: один из них на `1px` больше другого по высоте. Каким образом можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Дайте примеры кодов

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, там особо нечего приводить:

    width: 1.53em;
    height: 3.13em;

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в итоге решилась неожиданным для меня образом. Оказалось, что дело было в свойстве `transform`: изображение в `:after` повторяло то, что было задано для `:before`, но с трансформацией (`scaleX(-1)`), что в итоге и привело к подобным искажением. Трансформация картинки в редакторе и сохранение в уже отраженном состоянии решили проблему.